# For loop multiple arrays with blank lines preserved

Tags: android, arrays, bash, for-loop, awk

I have three files:

**file1**

```
one
uno
un
1
```

**file 2**

```
two
dos

2
```

**file 3**
    three
    tres
    trois
    3

Here is my script:

```
#!/system/bin/bash
list=($(cat /sdcard/lst1 )) 
list2=($(cat /sdcard/lst2 ))
list3=($(cat /sdcard/lst3 ))
for i in ${!list[*]} ; do 
echo -e "${list[$i]} ${list2[$i]} 
${list3[$i]} ; done
```

Here the output I got:

```
one two three
uno dos tres
un   2  trois
 1       3
```

Here the desired output:

```
one two three
uno dos tres
un      trois
 1   2   3
```

I also tried with:

```
IFS=$'\n' ; set -f ;
```

but it's still don't working ...

What do I have to change?

**It's on Android and there is no `paste` command.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
paste f1 f2 f3
```

should do the job which gives you

```
one two three
uno dos tres
un      trois
1   2   3
```

**Edit : In android where paste is not available by default**

If file1, file2, file3 are the three files then below script would do the job

```
 awk '{line[FNR]=(line[FNR]=="")?$0:line[FNR] "\t" $0}END{for(i=1;i<=FNR;i++){print line[i]}}' file*
```

**Output**

```
one two three
uno dos tres
un      trois
1   2   3
```

**References**

1. Awk [[ String Concatenation ]](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Concatenation.html#String-Concatenation)
2. Awk [[ For Statement ]](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/For-Statement.html#The-for-Statement).

Comment: `paste` uses tab as a delimiter by default. Use the `-d` flag to specify a delimiter. I think OP wants tabulated output but didn't explicitly say it.

Comment: I forgot to say its on android ... And there is no 'paste' command ... There is a way without paste ?

Comment: @vinsmv : Is `awk` available in android? Also, please update the question with the above information and add the `android` tag

Comment: @vinsmv : Saw the edit . In this case you can use awk, see the updated answer

Comment: @GregoryNisbet. Updated the answer as `paste` is not by default available in terminal emulator. I was thinking of piping the output to `column` in the beginning anyways. :)

Comment: @vinsmv : Added the references, just in case.

Answer (score 0):

Bash has the [`mapfile`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-mapfile) command (or its synonym, `readarray`) to read a file into an array, one line at a time. Unlike `list=($(cat file))`, which actually just splits the whole file into array elements using the `$IFS` shell variable (and thus drops the empty line), `mapfile` assigns an empty line to an array element.

Using just Bash, I'd write this as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in {1..3}; do
    # Assign file 1 to arr1, file2 to arr2 and file3 to arr3
    mapfile -t arr"$i" < file"$i"
done

# Loop over indices of arr1
for i in "${!arr1[@]}"; do
    # Print elements number i from each array
    printf '%s\t%s\t%s\n' "${arr1[i]}" "${arr2[i]}" "${arr3[i]}"
done
```

**Remarks:**

- Unlike for normal parameter assignments, the array name in `mapfile` can be "constructed".
- The `-t` option removes the trailing newlines.
- Instead of the [not universally portable `echo -e`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html), I'm using `printf`.
- None of the variables have to be quoted with this specific input, but it doesn't hurt to – especially in the arguments to `printf`.

Comment: Thx for the answer .. This is  also working  Perfectly !!